# Many-to-many relationships in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many

I have got a simple many-to-many relationship between tables User and Role, using 
UserRole table as a relationship one.
So, it looks like this: User->one-to-many-> UserRole <-many-to-one<-Role

User.cs:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
    }
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Role.cs:

```
public class Role
{
    public virtual Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

UserRole.cs:

```
public class UserRole
{
    public virtual Guid UserRoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual int CommonUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

UserMap.cs:

```cs
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UserId).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.UserName);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles)
            .Cascade.None()
            .Reverse()
            .Table("UserRole")
            .ParentKeyColumn("UserId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("RoleId");
    }
}
```

RoleMap.cs

```
class RoleMap : ClassMap<Role>
{
    public RoleMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.RoleId).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Users)
            .Cascade.None()
            .Table("UserRole")
            .ParentKeyColumn("RoleId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("UserId");
    }
}
```

UserRoleMap.cs:

```
public class UserRoleMap : ClassMap<UserRole>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UserRole).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
    }
}
```

My question is:
Is that possible in NHibernate to get a user from DB, add roles to it's collection and save. I know I am able to do this using UserRole table and just add / remove assosiations,
but is this possible to do the same without using UserRole class in my code (I mean in BL)?

Basically, if I want to add roles to user, can I add them to his collection and save, not by manipulating UserRole manually?
Also, UserRole should have GuidComb key, but when I am trying to add role - it throws an exception that UserRoleId can not be empty and profiler shows

```
INSERT INTO UserRole
(UserId, RoleId)
VALUES
(1, 'some-guid-here')
```

So it does not generate primary key for me

Many thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have to create a UserRole class. NHibernate ensures the associative table.

Models

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
    }

    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public virtual Guid RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UserId).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.UserName);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles)
           .Cascade.All()
           .Table("UserRoles");
    }
}

public class RoleMap : ClassMap<Role>
{
    public RoleMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.RoleId).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Users)
           .Cascade.All()
           .Inverse()
           .Table("UserRoles");
    }
}
```

Generated sql by NHibernate

```
create table [Role] (RoleId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null, Name NVARCHAR(255) null, primary key (RoleId))
create table UserRoles (Role_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null, User_id INT not null)
create table [User] (UserId INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, UserName NVARCHAR(255) null, primary key (UserId))
alter table UserRoles add constraint FK_UserRoles_User foreign key (User_id) references [User]
alter table UserRoles add constraint FK_UserRoles_Role foreign key (Role_id) references [Role]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but what if I want to add some additional columns to relationship table? For example, I would like to add CreatedDate?

Comment: @AlexOvechkin In such case, it is no more a pure association table. If you want to handle that by code, you should stick to your question implementation. (But it is strange the `UserRole` id is not generated, it should work as for any other entity.) Otherwise see this [related question](/q/36087683/1178314).